# "A yield expression is only allowed in a generator body" on Array.prototype.map()

Tags: typescript, redux-saga

Been asked to refactor this. The code is working but not sure what it's eventually going to break:

```
export function* fetchWidgetDataIfRequired(action) {
  yield call(taggedDelay, 102);
  const { dashboardId, dashboardType } = action.payload;

  const dashboard = yield select(makeSelectDashboard({ dashboardId, dashboardType }));
  const widgetData = yield select(makeSelectWidgets());

  const dashboardWidgets = dashboard.getIn(['config', 'widgets']);
  // get all widgets that have userWidgetId but no widgetLayoutData

  // NOTE: if you do not do valueSeq(), it will still work but it will throw a warning about
  // > [...effects] has been deprecated in favor of all([...effects]), please update your code
  const fetchWidgetLayoutDataActions = dashboardWidgets.filter((widget) => {
    '';

    const userWidgetId = widget.get('userWidgetId');

    return userWidgetId != null
      && widgetData.getIn([userWidgetId, 'widgetLayoutData']) == null;
  }).map((widget) => yield spawn(fetchWidgetLayoutData, { dashboardType, dashboardId, widget })).valueSeq().toArray();

  // console.error('fetchdata', {
  //   fetchWidgetLayoutDataActions,
  // });
  yield all(fetchWidgetLayoutDataActions);

  // get all widgets that have userWidgetId but no widgetData
  const fetchWidgetDataActions = dashboardWidgets.filter((widget) => {
    const userWidgetId = widget.get('userWidgetId');

    return userWidgetId != null
      && widgetData.getIn([userWidgetId, 'widgetData']) == null;
  }).map((widget) => {
    const userWidgetId = widget.get('userWidgetId');
    const delay = widget.get('y', 0) * 250 + 6;
    // const delay = 100;

    return spawn(fetchWidgetData, { userWidgetId, delay });
  }).valueSeq().toArray();
  yield all(fetchWidgetDataActions);
}
```

I'm getting thrown this error:

`A 'yield' expression is only allowed in a generator body.ts(1163)`

I would love to see how this could be coded better to avoid this error.

Comment: Added full context.

Answer (score 0):

Focus in on the function:

```
.map((widget) => { // NOT A GENERATOR 
    const userWidgetId = widget.get('userWidgetId');
    const delay = widget.get('y', 0) * 250 + 6;    
    return yield spawn(fetchWidgetData, { userWidgetId, delay }); // TRIED TO USE YIELD
  })
```

The error is because the function is not a generator but you tried to use yield.

## Fix

The code is *wrong* hence the the TypeScript complaining. We can only speculate on the correct code without full context but most likely the following is the correct:

```
.map((widget) => { 
    const userWidgetId = widget.get('userWidgetId');
    const delay = widget.get('y', 0) * 250 + 6;    
    return spawn(fetchWidgetData, { userWidgetId, delay }); // NO YIELD
  })
```

Comment: I tried this and received this:

`spawn effect must be yielded`

Comment: Added full context